# Error al recuperar contraseña PHPMailer, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, phpmailer

He implementado la recuperacion de contraseña por medio de PHPMailer, el correo si llega
[image: llega el correo]

Pero al darle click al enlace ya cuando añado el código PHP no me redirige a la pagina para cambiar la contraseña. Solo funciona sin el código por lo que estoy segura que allí esta el error
Este es el código PHP de recuperar.php en donde se introduce el correo

```
    <?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'DBusuarios.php';
    $errors = array();
    
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    
        if (!isEmail($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Debe ingresar un correo electronico valido";
    }
            if(emailExiste($email)){
                $user_id = getValor('id','correo',$email);
                $nombre = getValor('nombre','correo',$email);
    
                $token = generaTokenPass($user_id);
                $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/Mi-pagina/cambia_pass.php?user_id'.$user_id.'&token'.$token;
                $asunto = 'Recuperar contraseña';
                $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre: <br /><br /> Se ha solicitado una recuperacion de contraseña.<br />
                Para restaurar la contraseña, visita la siguiente dirección:<br /> <a href='$url'>Restablecer contraseña</a>";
    
                if(enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto,$cuerpo)){
                    echo "Hemos enviado un correo electronico a la dirección $email para
                    restablecer tu contraseña.<br />";
                    echo "<a href ='iniciar_sesion.php'>Iniciar sesión</a>";
                    exit;
                }else{
                    //"Error al enviar Email";
                }
                }else{
                $errors[] = "No existe el correo electronico.";
                }
    }
```

Esta es la funcion de generaTokenPass

```
function generaTokenPass($user_id){
        global $mysqli;

        $token = generateToken();
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET token_password=?, password_request=1 WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $token, $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        return $token;
    }
```

Y esta la funcion de getValor

```
function getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor)  {
        global $mysqli;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT $campo FROM usuarios WHERE $campoWhere = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $valor);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($num > 0){
            $stmt->bind_result($_campo);
            $stmt->fetch();
            return $_campo;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado en la página de cambiar_pass.php este es el codigo

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'DBusuarios.php';

    if(empty($_GET['user_id'])){
        header('Location:iniciar_sesion.php');
    }
    if(empty($_GET['token'])){
        header('Location:iniciar_sesion.php');
    }
    $user_id = $mysqli-> real_escape_string ($_GET['user_id']);
    $token = $mysqli-> real_escape_string ($_GET['token']);

    if(!verificaTokenPass($user_id, $token)){
        echo 'No se pudo verificar los datos';
        exit;
    }

?>
```

En la base de datos si se genera el token y también el password_request cambia su valor a 1 como indica la funcionpor lo que la conexión con la BD considero es correcta.

Entiendo que por el código y las sentencias de IF(EMPTY) no está recibiendo los valores del token pero no logro resolverlo.

He cambiado el mensaje del correo y para que envie la URL

```
$cuerpo = "Hola $nombre: <br /><br /> Se ha solicitado una recuperacion de contraseña.<br />
            Para restaurar la contraseña, visita la siguiente dirección:<br /> <a href='$url'>$url</a>";
```

Y esto es lo que recibo en el correo aunque igual al darle click no redirige a la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el navegador no aparece nada, directamente envía a la pagina de iniciar sesión. No entiendo donde debería colocar esa linea de código

Comment: Tienes un error en el enlace: `.'&token'.$token;` y no te va a llegar la variable `token`, porque falta el signo `=` entre variable y valor. Debería ser: `.'&token='.$token;`

Comment: Totalemente cierto